# Cannot invoke initializer for type with an argument list of type Swift

Tags: swift, initialization

I have an app with 12 ViewControllers. While I go from one ViewController to another I save the data to `Struct FullData`. 
In `class TwelvethViewController` I take the contents of `Struct FullData` and pass them as arguments to an instance of `FireBaseData`, but I get an error - cannot invoke initializer for type `FireBaseData`with an argument list of type`( (FirePostCode:String,FireSelectedBathRow:Int))

```
import Foundation
  Struct FullData {
    static  var finalPostCode:String!
    static  var finalSelectedBathRow:Int!
}


struct FireBaseData {
  var FirePostCode:String!
  var FireSelectedBathRow:Int!

   init(FirePostCode:String,FireSelectedBathRow:Int){
     self.FirePostCode = FirePostCode
     self.FireSelectedBathRow = FireSelectedBathRow
 }
}


class TwelvethViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBAction func saveToDB(sender: AnyObject) {
     let fireData = FireBaseData(FirePostCode: FullData.finalPostCode,
     FireSelectedBathRow: FullData.finalSelectedBathRow)
  }
}
```

Comment: @Alexander Momchliov for legibility purposes.

Comment: @Alexander Momchliov   Are you asking me why I have indented my code? Because this is what I have understood. To indent my code, I have added 4 spaces before each line.

Comment: Your line `self.FireSelectedBathRow = FireSelectedBathRow:Int` is part of the problem.

Comment: @ChrisH  That was not in my original code, it was a typo. I have updated the code, so it still does not solve my issue.

Comment: Your code shown above still has some "typo" and I cannot reproduce your issue with the code. Please check your code if it can reproduce your issue in the Playground or with a simplified new project.

Comment: @OOPer  The logic of my code was broken and thats why my code did not run.